# Created Links that are restricted to different groups

Tags: php, mysql

So Im trying to make a admin dashboard and restrict some links on my sidebar to different groups but I am unable to find out how to do this. Could someone put me in the right direction on this.

Currently I have a column on my phpmyadmin table called usergroup which I have set as a number. Here is my code to restrict user group

```
<?php if(usergroup=="1") {?>
      <li><a href="index2.html">Dashboard2</a></li>
<?php}?>
```

Thanks,

CaptainDan

Comment: You should at least try to write the code then post a question when you run in to an error or get stuck otherwise. We're not here to just write your code for you.

Comment: Do you have a type to manage different groups?

Comment: Google on "role permission php mysql" https://www.google.nl/search?q=role+permission+php+mysql  should give you some examples and tutorials

Comment: All you need to do is plan out what to do code-wise. We cannot help you create this master plan, from what your asking you just need if statements if a user is a certain group and echo the appropriate links.

Comment: From the code you just inputted in your edit, change it to `if ($usergroup === "1") { echo '<li><a href="index2.html">Dashboard2</a></li>'; }`

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the role in MySQL table column and set different roles like 1 for admin 2 for users 3 for subscriber and save the links for particular users. When you want to get the links for particular user you have to check the role first then get his link for ex if role==1 then get link.